# Hash functions multiplying key with constant

Tags: hash, key, hashtable, hash-function

How does a constant before the key in the formula:

```
h(k) = (const * key) % m,
```

affect the distribution of the hash values in the table?

Are there any rules on how to choose such a constant to minimize collisions and get an even distribution of the keys in the hash table?

Comment: It depends heavily on distribution of `key` values. If `key` is distributed uniformly, there can hardly be a reason for having any `const` other than 1. 

Regarding the rules, the first thing is to avoid divisors of the modulo. E.g. if `m` is divisible by `const`, some of hashtable buckets will never get hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant factor should be prime, and if I remember correctly it should be relatively prime w.r.t. the modulus. This is all discussed at great length in Knuth Volume III.